# MS CRM Charts in Queue not saving

Tags: charts, permissions, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create a chart in MS CRM and I keep getting an error.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed. Returned hr =   -2147187962, ObjectID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, OwnerId: e2e07c90-2105-e611-80f6-00155d293800,  OwnerIdType: 8 and CallingUser: e2e07c90-2105-e611-80f6-00155d293800. ObjectTypeCode: 1112, objectBusinessUnitId: b4bd5fdf-2ccf-e311-80ca-00155d293800, AccessRights: CreateAccess Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147187962</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
<Message>SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed. Returned hr = -2147187962, ObjectID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, OwnerId: e2e07c90-2105-e611-80f6-00155d293800,  OwnerIdType: 8 and CallingUser: e2e07c90-2105-e611-80f6-00155d293800. ObjectTypeCode: 1112, objectBusinessUnitId: b4bd5fdf-2ccf-e311-80ca-00155d293800, AccessRights: CreateAccess </Message>
<Timestamp>2016-08-08T06:05:22.5032353Z</Timestamp>
<InnerFault i:nil="true" />
<TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I understand this is a permissions error, but I can not find which permission to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectTypeCode: 1112` is the [user chart entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328086.aspx), and it looks like you are missing the `CreateAccess` right (e.g. create).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So on the Security Roles under User Charts ensure Create is selected.

Comment: Yes I think that's what your missing, only one way to be sure.